# Where is xcode command line tools installed to when using the downloaded pkg file?

Tags: xcode, macos-catalina, xcode12, xcode-command-line-tools

I have Xcode installed on my computer.  Initially I installed the xcode command line tools by prompt when opening Xcode.  In my Xcode preferences, in the locations section, command line tools read `Xcode 12.0 (12A7209)` and below it the path `/Applications/Xcode.app`.  However, as documented NUMEROUS times on stack overflow, Homebrew was not recognizing my xcode command line tools (CLT: N/A).  So I downloaded the pkg file from Apple Developer and reinstalled the command line tools with that pkg file as the command line install `xcode-select --install` didn't work.  The gui installer finished with no errors.  Now, Homebrew recognizes my CLT.

**Question:** if Xcode already installed command line tools, then what location did the downloaded pkg file from Apple developer install the command line tools too?  Did this leave me with 2 versions of the xcode command line tools on my system?

Running `xcode-select -p` outputs the following, as many people have already noted:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

**Additionally** `which -a xcode-select` also only returns `/usr/bin/xcode-select`.

What did the additional pkg installation do on my computer?

What's the use of having Xcode install the xcode command line tools when opening, if we have to re-install them from pkg anyway to get command line programs to read it?

Answer (score 0):

> if Xcode already installed command line tools, then what location did the downloaded pkg file from Apple developer install the command line tools too?

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

> Did this leave me with 2 versions of the xcode command line tools on my system?

Not exactly "xcode" command line tools, but two CLTs, yes. Ideally homebrew should use `xcrun` to find them and use whichever available.

> Running xcode-select -p outputs the following, as many people have already noted: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

That is correct and expected. If you have Xcode, the Xcode's CLTs should be used. If you delete Xcode, it should output:

```
/Library/Developer/
```

You can manually change this path by

```
xcode-select -s <path>
```

> What did the additional pkg installation do on my computer?

It just sits there for anyone to use it.

> What's the use of having Xcode install the xcode command line tools when opening, if we have to re-install them from pkg anyway to get command line programs to read it?

It's brew's bad to not use the already existing Xcode CLTs.

Comment: do you know of a way to have Brew recognize and use the Xcode CLT's?  Also, is there a separate command to utilize the pkg installed CLT's?  When I run xcrun --show-sdk-path it still outputs the Xcode CLT's path of /Applications/Xcode.app/Content/.....

Comment: You can create a symlink from Xcode's developer folder to /Library/Developer folder. Did you try setting the path manually using `-s` option ?

Comment: Why would I symlink the XCLTS's to the CLT's installed by the pkg?  Or did you mean the other way around?  I'll try, but is there a specific executable to symlink?  Also, what does changing the path manually do to the other programs (if there are any) that currently use the XCLT's?